# How to exctract ECDH parameters from an OpenSSL-generated $G$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, openssl

1. I'm using ECDH for generating ECDH public parameters (p,a,b,G,n), I try to get this values using `openssl ecparam -in cert.pem -text -noout`

   For `Generator` $G=(x,y)$ I get :

   ```
   Generator (uncompressed):
     04:aa:87:ca:22:be:8b:05:37:8e:b1:c7:1e:f3:20:
     ad:74:6e:1d:3b:62:8b:a7:9b:98:59:f7:41:e0:82:
     54:2a:38:55:02:f2:5d:bf:55:29:6c:3a:54:5e:38:
     72:76:0a:b7:36:17:de:4a:96:26:2c:6f:5d:9e:98:
     bf:92:92:dc:29:f8:f4:1d:bd:28:9a:14:7c:e9:da:
     31:13:b5:f0:b8:c0:0a:60:b1:ce:1d:7e:81:9d:7a:
     43:1d:7c:90:ea:0e:5f
   ```

   My question is, how to extract $x$ (the x-coordinate of the generator $G$) and $y$ (the y-coordinate of the generator $G$) values from this answer.
2. by the way: when displaying ECDH parameters I get a seed value. Can someone please explain what this value is useful for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be off-topic since it is really about OpenSSL... For your question 1, the values you get are the prefix `04` (which indicates that the point is represented in uncompressed form) followed by the $x$- and $y$-coordinates of the generator. Here you have 97 bytes, so eliminate the first byte and then you have both coordinates, which take 48 bytes each.

```
firas@aoba ~ % foo="  04:aa:87:ca:22:be:8b:05:37:8e:b1:c7:1e:f3:20:
firas@aoba ~ dquote>   ad:74:6e:1d:3b:62:8b:a7:9b:98:59:f7:41:e0:82:
firas@aoba ~ dquote>   54:2a:38:55:02:f2:5d:bf:55:29:6c:3a:54:5e:38:
firas@aoba ~ dquote>   72:76:0a:b7:36:17:de:4a:96:26:2c:6f:5d:9e:98:
firas@aoba ~ dquote>   bf:92:92:dc:29:f8:f4:1d:bd:28:9a:14:7c:e9:da:
firas@aoba ~ dquote>   31:13:b5:f0:b8:c0:0a:60:b1:ce:1d:7e:81:9d:7a:
firas@aoba ~ dquote>   43:1d:7c:90:ea:0e:5f"
firas@aoba ~ % python -c "print 0x$(printf $foo | tr -d ': \n' | tail -c +3 | head -c 96)"
26247035095799689268623156744566981891852923491109213387815615900925518854738050089022388053975719786650872476732087
firas@aoba ~ % python -c "print 0x$(printf $foo | tr -d ': \n' | tail -c +3 | tail -c 96)"
8325710961489029985546751289520108179287853048861315594709205902480503199884419224438643760392947333078086511627871
```

Comment: Where is the "04" documentation?  By the way, you're a life-saver.

Comment: @AndyNovocin As mentioned in `man ecparam`, see RFC3279 and its references (notably ANSI X9.62-1998).

Comment: Thanks, I found it.  If anyone else is curious it's specified in  Section 4.3.7 of X9.62-1998.